# Server 2012 .NET Core 2 App runs fine on Kestrel, but not IIS 7, likely a CORS issue

Tags: iis-7, cors, .net-core

I wrote a .NET Core 2 app as a back end API application.  It runs fine in Visual Studio 2017, and works great on my dev machine.  The front end is Angular.

It runs on port 55564.  The Angular runs on the same server, but port 80.

The server is Server 2012 with IIS-7.  I set it up per instructions I found on the internet, and I cannot get IIS to serve the pages.  I continuously get error 400 (not 404) which appears to be some type of CORS issues.  I do have CORS implemented in my app.

When I open a command prompt in the web root directly, and kick off Kestral directly using 'dotnet XXXXX.dll', it works perfectly.  Everything runs great.
So for now, it's running from command prompt and working perfectly.  This implies that it's a configuration error, and not in my app.  But I do want to get it running from IIS.  I really can't figure out what I am missing.

IIS 7 - Setup
I created a standard website.  I set it to 'no managed code'.  I set up the host headers to respond to 'localhost:55564'.  In the app pool, I assigned the identity to a specific userid that has full ownership of the web root folder.

In my global HandlerMappings.
    OPTIONSVerbHandler
    * for path
    Handler is IsapiModule
    Executable: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

I then pushed the options verb to be the very first handler mapping.

In my program.cs:

```
WebHost
.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    logging.AddConsole();
    logging.AddDebug();
})
.CaptureStartupErrors(true)
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseUrls("http://*:55564")
.Build();
```

In my startup.cs, under ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});
```

In my startup.cs, under Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\XXXXX.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm out of ideas.  I've looked at dozens of posts.  Not sure what I am missing.

But since it works from the command line, just not from IIS-7, I believe it has to be an IIS-7 configuration issue.

Comment: What makes you think it's a CORS problem? What is the message that comes as part of the 400 error?

Comment: I thought it was maybe CORS because of the trace I was getting.  Turns out, the issue was .UseIISIntegration() missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to add `UseIISIntegration()` in your startup.cs ?

```
WebHost
.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    logging.AddConsole();
    logging.AddDebug();
})
.CaptureStartupErrors(true)
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseUrls("http://*:55564")
.Build();
```

Comment: Wow.  That fixed it!  I've never seen that anywhere listed.